# How can I install grub customizer without using any command?

Tags: installation, grub2

I want to install grub customizer but unable to install it from command line.

Is there any setup file of this tool like a setup of any software in Windows, so I can install it from GUI

Comment: could you tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 2):

open your Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources. Then, on the "Other Software" tab, click "Add" and enter the PPA under the same

[image]

```
 ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

then updating cache will be done automatically  .now open your software center and type

`grub-customizer` in your search box . it will be there to install .

All the best.